# Convert postgres to Knex

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I am having trouble converting this from a postgres format into a knex format.
Someone here is a genius who could help me

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (email) *
    FROM   feelings
    WHERE not email = 'hello@gmail.com'
    ORDER  BY email, created_at DESC 
    
     ) sub
ORDER  BY created_at DESC;
```

Comment: The code you show is just a snippet and will not work anywhere. If you want a solution you will need to update your question to include 1) The complete query 2) What you did in Knex? 3) The error message that resulted when it did not work.

Comment: Question 1) answered, you still need to respond to 2) and 3).